# Randomizing strings without duplication

Tags: string, random, duplicates

I have string with 5 different sayings and I'm trying to make them random without any duplication and repeat the saying once they all have been picked.

so far i have

final String[] mySays = { " x ", " y ", " z" , " a ", " b",}

@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //change number to however number there is of "saying"
                int aNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
                textOne.setText(mySays[aNumber]);

what can i add to this?

any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>(){{
        add("a");
        add("b");
        add("c");
        add("d");
        add("e");
    }};

   List<String> dupeList = new ArrayList<String>(){{addAll(myStrings);}};
    Random r = new Random();

    public String pick(){
            String retval="";
    int pos;
    switch (dupeList.size()){
        case 1: 
            retval = dupeList.get(0);
            dupeList.clear();
            dupeList.addAll(myStrings);
            return retval;
        default:
            pos = r.nextInt(dupeList.size());
            retval = dupeList.get(pos);
            dupeList.remove(pos);
            return retval;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach that uses an ArayList simulate "picking out of hat" kind of thing you want to do.  ArrayList is convenient because you can remove elements easily, and then pick randomly from what's left on the list.

```
List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("A");
    add("B");
    add("C");
    add("D");
    add("E");
}};
List<String> dupeList = new ArrayList<String>() {{addAll(myStrings);}};
Random r = new Random();

public String pick() {
    String retval = "";
    int pos;
    switch (dupeList.size()) {
        case 1:
            retval = dupeList.get(0);
            dupeList.clear();
            dupeList.addAll(myStrings);
            return retval;
        default:
            pos = r.nextInt(dupeList.size());
            retval = dupeList.get(pos);
            dupeList.remove(pos);
            return retval;
    }
}
```

So once you have defined this pick() method, you can just call it to set the text each time.

```
 `text1.setText(pick());`
```

Comment: i'm getting red line when i enter dupeList. i'm using android studio btw. maybe thats why?

Comment: Sorry not clear on where you are getting the error.  Did you declare it first as in the above example?  e.g. List<String> dupeList = new . .  .

Comment: Did you import List and ArrayList? as in import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List; at the top of the file just below the package directive?

Comment: I did. its listed. the error is "cannot resolve symbol 'dupeList'

Comment: That's very odd. I ran this code in Android on my machine and it worked find.  If its saying cannot resolve symbol dupeList it means that for some reason your variable declaration isn't being recognized Usually that's some kind of spelling or capitalization mistake, like trying to use dupeList when you declared dupelist.

Comment: Post your code and maybe I'll see something thats not obvious.

Comment: yeah all the dupeList are underlined red.

Comment: Only other thing I can think is that you've declared dupeList inside a method like onCreate, instead of at class level, so its not visible to pick method. Hard to say without seeing it.